# Why paginate widget is not including my query string parameters?

Tags: pagination, typo3-9.x, tx-news

I have news listing including pagination with news tags. When i am paginate through news(or any custom extension) it bypass parameter.

[image]
On page /tag the pagination links should look like this: **`/tag/seite/2`** but i just get **`/seite/2`** without any parameters.

Any ideas what i am doing wrong/how to solve my issue?

Answer (score 0):

I tried it by adding `addQueryStringMethod="GET"` as parameter in `<f:widget.link>` and it works!